# How to add a constraint in a google geocoding API request

Tags: geocoding, google-maps-api

I'm trying to get the center point of some localities using the geocoding API from google.

95% of the requests get the expected result but from time to time the API give me an unexpected result because the name of my locality is also the name of a natural feature. In thoses cases the coordinates indicate the natural feature and not the locality.

So for example I have this request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Le Gibloux+FR+Switzerland&MY_API_KEY
```

Which give me this result

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Le Gibloux",
               "short_name" : "Le Gibloux",
               "types" : [ "establishment", "natural_feature" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Sorens",
               "short_name" : "Sorens",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },... and so on
          ],
         "formatted_address" : "Le Gibloux, 1642 Sorens, Suisse",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 46.68413690000001,
               "lng" : 7.0403161
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 46.69179099999999,
                  "lng" : 7.0563235
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 46.6764818,
                  "lng" : 7.0243087
               }
            }
         }
```

I would like to constraint the request to get only features with a type "locality, political".

I try to add some `&types=locality`, or `&address_components=locality`,... in the request but unfortunatly, I always get the natural feature first.

Did you know how to set a constraint with this API ?

Comment: I believe you can request &components=sublocality:Sorens

Comment: Indeed, it work.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by @Mapperz in the comments,

You can add to your request:

```
&components=sublocality:NameOfMyLocality
```

or

```
&components=locality:NameOfMyLocality
```